# Operador corchetes y paréntesis, ¿Cómo escoger la sobrecarga correcta?

Tags: c++, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Quisiera acceder a ciertos datos de una clase usando el operador corchetes (`[]`) pero dependiendo del tipo del índice dentro de los corchetes devolver un tipo de dato u otro. Como ejemplo simplificado:

```
struct S
{
    int   &operator []( int indice ) { std::cout << "[i]"; return i_bufer[indice]; }
    short &operator [](short indice) { std::cout << "[s]"; return s_bufer[indice]; }

private:
    int   i_bufer[10]{ 0,  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9  };
    short s_bufer[10]{ 0, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999 };
};
```

No existe manera de escribir un literal de tipo `short`, así que la única manera de escoger la sobrecarga `short` es con una conversión de tipos:

```
S s;
std::cout << s[9] << '\n';        // muestra [i]9
std::cout << s[(short)9] << '\n'; // muestra [s]999
```

Pero esta aproximación no me gusta y me preguntaba si hay otras opciones.

### ¿Qué he intentado?

#### Parámetros *etiquetados*.

En primer lugar he intentado *etiquetar* los parámetros:

```
struct S
{
    enum class tipo_i : std::int32_t {};
    enum class tipo_s : std::int32_t {};

    int   &operator [](tipo_i indice)
    { std::cout << "[i]"; return i_bufer[static_cast<int>(indice)]; }
    short &operator [](tipo_s indice)
    { std::cout << "[s]"; return s_bufer[static_cast<int>(indice)]; }

private:
    int   i_bufer[10]{ 0,  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9  };
    short s_bufer[10]{ 0, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999 };
};
```

Funciona, pero es un poco verboso:

```
S s;
std::cout << s[9] << '\n';            // error, no hay sobrecarga disponible
std::cout << s[S::tipo_i{9}] << '\n'; // muestra [i]9
std::cout << s[S::tipo_s{9}] << '\n'; // muestra [s]999
```

#### Plantilla.

Como idea loca, quise intentar hacer una plantilla del operador:

```
struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    T &operator [](T) { std::cout << "???"; return 0; }

private:
    int   i_bufer[10]{ 0,  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9  };
    short s_bufer[10]{ 0, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999 };
};

template <>
int   &S::operator [](int indice)   { std::cout << "[i]"; return i_bufer[indice]; }
template <>
short &S::operator [](short indice) { std::cout << "[s]"; return s_bufer[indice]; }
```

La versión de la plantilla se comporta como la versión original, pero no existe una manera fácil de especificar el parametro-tipo junto con el operador:

```
S s;
std::cout << s[9] << '\n';        // muestra [i]9 igual que antes
std::cout << s[(short)9] << '\n'; // muestra [s]999 igual que antes
std::cout << s<short>[9] << '\n'; // s no es una plantilla
std::cout << s[9]<short> << '\n'; // sin sentido
// Correcto, pero completamente verboso y dificil de leer y escribir
std::cout << s.operator[]<short>(9) << '\n';
```

#### Pregunta.

Los problemas descritos suceden también con el operador paréntesis, quisiera saber si hay más alternativas de las que no soy consciente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No existe manera de escribir un literal de tipo short, así que la única manera de escoger la sobrecarga short es con una conversión de tipos

Efectivamente no hay una manera de escribir un literal tipo `short`... cualquier casteo a `short` tendrá que ser explícito ya que si no el compilador interpretará el valor como `int` y, en consecuencia, realizará la primera llamada.

> Pero esta aproximación no me gusta y me preguntaba si hay otras opciones.

¿Y qué es lo que no te gusta exactamente de dicha solución?

Desde luego la solución con templates, para la firma que pretendes, no es viable:

```
    template <typename T>
    T& operator [](T) { std::cout << "???"; return 0; }
//  ^^                                             ^
// No puedes devolver un literal como referencia!!!
```

Así pues pocas alternativas te quedan:

- Si usas literales tendrás que hacer, al menos, un cast explícito (esto no se va a solucionar con wrappers ni con templates)
- Si usas variables entonces el propio tipo de la variable será quien determine a qué función se llama.

Por otro lado, si buscas un sistema un pelín más amigable quizás te resulte interesante hacer uso de una función de soporte:

```
struct S
{
    int   &operator []( int indice ) { std::cout << "[i]"; return i_bufer[indice]; }
    short &operator [](short indice) { std::cout << "[s]"; return s_bufer[indice]; }

private:
    int   i_bufer[10]{ 0,  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9  };
    short s_bufer[10]{ 0, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999 };
};

template<class T>
T& Helper(S s, T indice)
{ return s[indice]; }

int main()
{
  S s;
  std::cout << s[9] << '\n';               // muestra [i]9 igual que antes
  std::cout << s[(short)9] << '\n';               // muestra [s]999 igual que antes
  std::cout << Helper<int>(s,9) << '\n';   // muestra [i]9
  std::cout << Helper<short>(s,9) << '\n'; // muestra [s]999
}
```

Pero sinceramente no solo no le veo ventajas a esta posible solución respecto sino que es más engorrosa ya que el código es menos legible. Quizás deberías describir con más detalle qué no te gusta de tu primera solución para enfocar mejor posibles soluciones.

---

**EDITO:**

Una posible solución (si compilas bajo C++11 o superior), aunque tiene sus contras como veremos, es el uso de sufijos definidos por el usuario. La idea entonces es forzar el casting de una forma un poco más limpia.

El mayor inconveniente de los sufijos es que el parámetro de la función debe ser uno equivalente a los tipos enumerados en la siguiente lista:

```
const char*
unsigned long long int
long double
char
wchar_t
char16_t
char32_t
const char*, std::size_t
const wchar_t*, std::size_t
const char16_t*, std::size_t
const char32_t*, std::size_t
```

Como vemos no existe un literal cuya entrada sea `int`, pero si tenemos `unsigned long long int`. Asumiendo que no es la función más recomendable salvo que se use con cuidado podemos declarar el siguiente sufijo:

```
constexpr short operator "" _short( unsigned long long int valor)
{
  return static_cast<short>(valor);
}
```

Y ahora lo usamos:

```
int main()
{
  S s;
  std::cout << s[9] << '\n';        // muestra [i]9
  std::cout << s[(short)9] << '\n'; // muestra [s]999
  std::cout << s[9_short] << '\n';  // muestra [s]999
}
```

Comment: La estructura `S` es sólo ejemplo. Mi caso de uso es una clase `matriz2D` que puede ser accedida por filas o columnas. Así pues `m.fila(1)[0]` devuelve el primer elemento de la segunda fila y `m.columna(3)[1]` devuelve el segundo elemento de la cuarta columna. Quería una notación de doble corchete: `m[columna{3}][1]` que es la notación natural para matrices. (ya tengo el helper para el retorno del operador corchete).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster mientras comentabas estaba editando la respuesta Revisa la parte nueva a ver si te sirve de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

La struct S probablemente represente algo, a la vez que i_buffer y s_buffer tengan algún significado. Esa información adicional se puede incluir como parte de la semántica de los operadores. Por ejemplo:

```
struct Mes {
    Mes(int m) : m(m) {}
    int m;
};

struct Dia {
    Dia(int d) : d(d) {}
    int d;
};

struct S {
    int& operator[](const Mes& mes) 
    {
        std::cout << "[i]";
        return i_bufer[mes.m];
    }
    short& operator[](const Dia& dis) 
    {
        std::cout << "[s]";
        return s_bufer[dis.d];
    }
private:
    int i_bufer[10]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    short s_bufer[10]{ 0, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999 };
};


int main()
{
    S s;
    std::cout << s[Mes(9)] << '\n'; // muestra [i]9
    std::cout << s[Dia(9)] << '\n'; // muestra [s]999
}
```

Comment: Eso es lo que he hecho cuando he intentado lo de "**Parámetros *etiquetados***".

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster En la forma de uso pueden verse similares, pero son conceptos diferentes :)

Comment: Tú usaste una `struct`, yo usé una `enum class` interna, mismo comportamiento con diferente aproximación.

Comment: Muy gracioso, pero no.

Comment: No veo la gracia. Ni veo la diferencia entre usar un `struct` para desambiguar llamadas y usar una `enum class` para el mismo propósito. Ambos casos usan un tipo diferenciado para desambiguar llamadas. ¿Hay algo que me esté pasando por alto?

Comment: Lo siento, no puedo ayudarte.